# Replacing a // comment line in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use `preg_replace` to delete any lines in a string that begin with `//`.

My code so far:

`$str = preg_replace('#^//(.*)?$#', '', $str);`

It's not deleting anything.

Comment: You are looking for `preg_replace('#^//.*\R?#m', '', $str)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the `m` modifier. Without it, `^` and `$` mean the start and end *of the string.* With `m` they refer to the start and end *of a line*.

```
$str = preg_replace('#^//(.*)?$#m', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have anchored the expression to the beginning and end of a line. Not sure if that's intentional or not, as that would only cover full line comments.

Also, as stated by @daniel-williams, by default, the `^$` matches beginning and end of string, not beginning and end of lines.

The following will work for any `//` comments anywhere (and only out the current line as `.` doesn't match line-breaks by default):

```
$result = preg_replace('%//(.*)%', '', $subject);
```

Or this one, if you want to also catch any whitespace in front of the comment:

```
$result = preg_replace('%\p{Zs}*//(.*)%u', '', $subject);
```

If you want to also remove any whitespace *and* newlines in front of a comment, *and* make sure there is at least 1 piece of whitespace before the comment (to not mess up URLs), you could try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('%\s+//.*%', '', $subject);
```

And to also cover `#` comments:

```
$result = preg_replace('%\s+(?://|#).*%', '', $subject);
```

Comment: Got some strange behavior. It seems to replace it with a line break.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Hm, it really shouldn't... Works on my machine™  That said, if the line only includes a comment, and the comment is removed, you will be left with an "extra" empty line though...

Comment: Btw, when working with regular expressions, I _highly_ recommend getting yourself a copy of https://www.regexbuddy.com. One of the tools I'm super happy I spent money on way back, as I keep turning back to it to both make, understand, and "debug" regular expressions. 

Comment: I added `\r\n` to the end, so it removes the line break and this now works. `$str = preg_replace('%\p{Zs}*//(.*)\r\n%u', '', $str);` Thanks for your help.

Comment: I noticed that it will turn `var url = 'http://www.example.com';` to `var url = 'http` so it's chopping off the rest of the string. Can you please modify your solution so it only looks for spaces or tabs before the `//`?

Comment: I solved it with this `^( )*(/{2,}|#)(.*)$`

Comment: @DanielWilliams Added a couple more variants now, which will make sure it's at least one whitespace (`*` vs `+`), and also eat up any newlines in front of the comment (which is safer than doing it after the comment, since that might "merge" code lines that shouldn't be merged...